# Cannot access PHP stdClass property after PDO::FETCH_OBJ

Tags: php, pdo

I've successfully connected to an IBM i5 and the following lines:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query('select fpdesc from mylib.myfile');
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($row);
echo '<br>$row[FPDESC] returns '.$row[FPDESC];
```

produce the following 2 lines of output:

```
array(1) { 
  ["FPDESC"]=> string(30) "ATLANTA " 
}

$row[FPDESC] returns ATLANTA
```

So far so good.  But the following lines:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query('select fpdesc from mylib.myfile');
$obj = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
var_dump($obj);
echo '<br>$obj->FPDESC returns '.$obj->FPDESC;
```

produce the following 2 lines of output:

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) { 
    ["FPDESC"]=> string(30) "ATLANTA " 
}

$obj->FPDESC returns
```

Why am I unable to echo the FPDESC property?  The only thing I can think of is scoping, but I'm really at a loss as to the fix.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does it work for lowercase? $obj->fpdesc?

Comment: try with `$obj->fpdesc` lowercase

Comment: I'm not sure, but I doubt this is your actual code. `"ATLANTA "` is not 30 chars long. What you described above should work.

Comment: You should get notices unless there is a constant named `FPDESC`. These notices don't explain your problem, but raising your error reporting should be your first step.

Comment: This is the actual code. The fpdesc field in the IBM DB2 file is defined as 30 characters long.  I also tried using trim(FPDESC) in the sql statement which reflected as 7 chars in the class property, but didn't change the inability to echo it. Lowercase does not work either.

Comment: I'll look into raising the error reporting. For now:

Comment: Iterate over and var_dump the keys:  `foreach ($obj as $key => $val) { var_dump($key); }` to see **exactly** what the issue is...

Comment: The property is showing as not set even though the var_dump shows a value.

Comment: Doing the foreach...var_dump($key) gave the following:    string(6) "FPDESC"

Comment: Is there anything involving visiblity or scoping that would cause an object property to show a value using `var_dump` and `print_r` but would cause that same object property to show as not set using `isset($obj->property)`?  Data is definitely being retrieved, given that `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` works and the stdClass object property shows ATLANTA. Perhaps it has something to do with the way PDO is interacting with the ibm DB2 database.

Comment: The `$obj->fpdesc` is throwing '`Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$fpdesc`, using both uppercase and lowercase. @redcoder had a similar issue back in Aug titled **php stdClass : assigning object value to variable** that was never answered. I'm thinking it has something to do with PDO & ibm.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your key name needs to match the case you used in your SQL statement.

so if

```
select fpdesc from mylib.myfile
```

it should be

```
$obj->fpdesc // not $obj->FPDESC.
```

With the same reasoning... if

```
select fpDESC from my lib.myfile
```

it should be

```
$obj->fpDESC
```